# Explanation of Docker Attach payload

Tags: docker

In the docker documentation there is a piece about the api for attach to logs.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/attach-to-a-container

There is this line I don't understand:

> SIZE1, SIZE2, SIZE3, SIZE4 are the four bytes of the uint32 size encoded as big endian.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an 8 byte header packet, and a uint32 exceeds the size for one byte and would be different for different platforms ([little vs big endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)). So Docker has explicitly defined the format for their uint32 packet over the network. Look into integer network vs host formatting for more details, in c, you have functions like `uint32 htonl(uint32)` where you'd pass in the 4 byte network formatted integer to get out the host formatted integer.

Comment: Thanks for answering, still very complicated for what I know, I just trying to show the logs on my website. I get the first byte shows which type it is, but not how to use the size.

Comment: Attaching is very different from showing the logs. Attaching creates an interactive session and it's implementing a stream, probably with tty and multiple io channels, over the rest protocol. If you just want to output the logs to a webpage, I'd use the [logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/get-container-logs) api.

Comment: Do you know what it is used for, because that is not very clear either from the docs!

Comment: See the documentation the cli's for `docker attach` vs `docker logs`, very different commands. These API's are just the back ends for those.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the uint32 size encoded as big endian